# PHP login page using MS SQL as database

Tags: php, sql-server, authentication

just wanna ask on how can I make a login page where-in the user will input the username and password. I have a simple code here but it does not work:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $user = $_POST['usr']; 
  $pass = $_POST['pwd'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM [master].[dbo].[userTbl] WHERE [username] = '$user' AND [password] = '$pass'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
if($user == $pass){
echo "Success";
}else{ 
echo "Invalid username/password";
```

Nevermind the $conn, it is for my database connection which is 100% working.
Feel free to edit my code or give some inputs, I know something is wrong here in the validation part.

Comment: Syntax error, missing double quote. Also, which PHP version are you using? `sqlsrv_query()` may not be available in your PHP version.

Comment: And why is your `Success` condition `$user == $pass` ? It doesn't make sense. I think your `Success` condition needs to count the number of rows your `$result` returns.

Comment: guys, I am using the latest version of php and sqlsrv is only for MS SQL. And my databse is MS SQL,

Comment: yes, i do need the count number in which case i do not know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your code to count the number of rows with matching username and password. If the count is 1 then only login.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM [master].[dbo].[userTbl] WHERE [username] = '$user' AND [password] = '$pass'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
$num = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
if($num==1){
    echo "Success";}
else{
    echo "Invalid username/password";}
```

Comment: I would recommend to use PDO instead of sqlsrv_query. More info: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: I am more into sqlsrv because this is the last part of my my web project :D, I don't want to use different syntax

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but I tried to enter correct username and password, but it sill echo "invalid username/password", where should i add the code to verify if the username and password are correct.

Comment: We are verifying the username and password by counting the number of rows which have same combination. This could happen only once in a database or 0 times. 0 = when no such combination found. 1 = when a combination is found.

Comment: hmm, i tried to make an example in my database wherein i tried to add a username and password. username:root password:root, tried to enter this in the textbox, still it echoes "Invalid Username/password"

Comment: Try fetching the array, this way it will tell us whether the query is working properly or not. After `$num = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);`, fetch the array and echo it. Lets see what comes out.

Comment: this is weird, i tried to echo $result, it shows resource id #5, and i can't echo $num, it does not show anything

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM [master].[dbo].[userTbl] WHERE [username] = '$user' AND [password] = '$pass';` Replace count distinct userid by asterisk.

Comment: wait, I don't get what you've said Sir. :) what do you mean by "Replace count distinct userid by asterisk".

Comment: currently number 5 being returned to you. I think it represents the user_id. Please paste the sql query again, which you are running.

Comment: but I only have 2 registered id in my database. i mean 2 pairs of accounts in my table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82661/discussion-between-varunsinghal-and-jim-steven).